# Return the last record entered in mysql

Tags: mysql, record

I used this command but I do not think it makes much sense

```
$get_lastID = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.`ID` DESC");
$fetch_resultID = mysql_fetch_array($get_lastID);
$lastID = $fetch_resultID['ID'];
```

Comment: Try adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.

Comment: This code is useful if your table is structured in such a way that the ID field is used and each ID is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you can order by ID and just need the last, how about fetching max(id)?

Comment: It returns the largest number, but what if our numbers were not in order?